# adding files to my project

Tags: android, android-file

I want to add a folder containing rules for some manipulations that will be performed during run time. The file names do not fulfill the name conventions (for example `dd-pp-f4.cib`), so I cannot put them inside `raw` resource folder. There are about 1000 files and many internal dependencies within so I can't change the file names.

How can I add a folder with those files to the project and load them during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

you can put them in the assets folder. 
Have a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html